# Confusion about boost::asio::io_context::run

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, mqtt, boost-asio

I am currently working on a project where I use the MQTT protocol for communication.

There is a Session class in a dedicated file which basically just sets up the publish handler, i.e. the callback that is invoked, when this client receives a message (the handler checks if the topic matches "ZEUXX/var", then deserialized the binary content of the frame and subsequently unsubscribes the topic):

session.hpp:

```
class Session
{
public:
  Session()
  {
    comobj = MQTT_NS::make_sync_client(ioc, "localhost", "1883", MQTT_NS::protocol_version::v5);
    using packet_id_t = typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*comobj)>::packet_id_t;

    // Setup client
    comobj->set_client_id(clientId);
    comobj->set_clean_session(true);

    /* If someone sends commands to this client */
    comobj->set_v5_publish_handler( // use v5 handler
        [&](MQTT_NS::optional<packet_id_t> /*packet_id*/,
            MQTT_NS::publish_options pubopts,
            MQTT_NS::buffer topic_name,
            MQTT_NS::buffer contents,
            MQTT_NS::v5::properties /*props*/) {
          std::cout << "[client] publish received. "
                    << " dup: " << pubopts.get_dup()
                    << " qos: " << pubopts.get_qos()
                    << " retain: " << pubopts.get_retain() << std::endl;
          std::string_view topic = std::string_view(topic_name.data(), topic_name.size());
          std::cout << "         -> topic: " << topic << std::endl;
          
          else if (topic.substr(0, 9) == "ZEUXX/var")
          {
            std::cout << "[client] reading variable name: " << topic.substr(10, topic.size() - 9) << std::endl;
            auto result = 99; // dummy variable, normally an std::variant of float, int32_t uint8_t 
                              // obtained by deserialzing the binary content of the frame                             
            std::cout << comobj->unsubscribe(std::string{topic});
          }
          return true;
        });
  }

  void readvar(const std::string &varname)
  {
    comobj->publish(serialnumber + "/read", varname, MQTT_NS::qos::at_most_once);
    comobj->subscribe(serialnumber + "/var/" + varname, MQTT_NS::qos::at_most_once);
  }

  void couple()
  {
    comobj->connect();
    ioc.run();
  }

  void decouple()
  {
    comobj->disconnect();
    std::cout << "[client] disconnected..." << std::endl;
  }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<
      MQTT_NS::callable_overlay<
          MQTT_NS::sync_client<MQTT_NS::tcp_endpoint<as::ip::tcp::socket, as::io_context::strand>>>>
      comobj;
  boost::asio::io_context ioc;
};
```

The client is based on a `boost::asio::io_context` object which happens to be the origin of my confusion. In my main file I have the following code.

main.cpp:

```
#include "session.hpp"

int main() 
{
    Session session; 
    session.couple();
    session.readvar("speedcpu");
}
```

Essentially, this creates an instance of the class Session and the couple member invokes the `boost::asio::io_context::run` member. This runs the io_context object's event processing loop and blocks the main thread, i.e. the third line in the main function will never be reached.

I would like to initiate a connection (session.couple) and subsequently do my publish and subscribe commands (session.readvar). My question is: How do I do that correctly?

Conceptionally what I aim for is best expressed by the following python-code:

```
    client.connect("localhost", 1883)

    # client.loop_forever() that's what happens at the moment, the program 
    # doesn't continue from here

    # The process loop get's started, however it does not block the program and 
    # one can send publish command subsequently.
    client.loop_start()

    while True:
         client.publish("ZEUXX/read", "testread")
         time.sleep(20)
```

Running the io_context object in a separate thread seems not to be working the way I tried it, any suggestions on how to tackle this problem? What I tried is the following:

Adaption in session.hpp

```
// Adapt the couple function to run io_context in a separate thread
void couple()
{
   comobj->connect();
   std::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &ioc));  
   t.detach();
}
```

Adpations in main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Session session; 
    session.couple();
    std::cout << "successfully started io context in separate thread" << std::endl;
    session.readvar("speedcpu");
}
```

The std::cout line is now reached, i.e. the program does not get stuck in the couple member of the class by io_context.run(). However directly after this line I get an error: "The network connection was aborted by the local system".

The interesting thing about this is that when I use `t.join()` instead of `t.detach()` then there is no error, however I have the same behavior with `t.join()` as when I call `io_context.run()` directly, namely blocking the program.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? If you're running into errors with threads running the `io_context::run` this is often solved by defining `BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED` before the asio includes.

Comment: To clarify, there is no error involved with ```boost::asio::io_context```, however as soon as the run method is invoked, the program ends up in a forever loop which means I cannot make any calls of ```readvar``` after the process loop has started.

Comment: What problems do you have with running it in a separate thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comment to the existing answer:

> `io_context.run()` never return because it never runs out of work (it is being kept alive from the MQTT server). As a result, the thread gets blocked as soon as I enter the `run()` method and I cannot send any publish and subscribe frames anymore. That was when I thought it would be clever to run the `io_context` in a separate thread to not block the main thread. However, when I `detach` this separate thread, the connection runs into an error, if I use `join` however, it works fine but the main thread gets blocked again.

I'll assume you know how to get this running successfully in a separate thread. The "problem" you're facing is that since `io_context` doesn't run out of work, calling `thread::join` will block as well, since it will wait for the thread to stop executing. The simplest solution is to call `io_context::stop` before the `thread::join`. From [the official docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/stop.html):

> This function does not block, but instead simply signals the `io_context` to stop. All invocations of its `run()` or `run_one()` member functions should return as soon as possible. Subsequent calls to `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` will return immediately until `restart()` is called.

That is, calling `io_context::stop` will cause the `io_context::run` call to return ("as soon as possible") and thus make the related thread joinable.

You will also want to save the reference to the `thread` somewhere (possibly as an attribute of the `Session` class) and only call `thread::join` *after* you've done the rest of the work (e.g. called the `Session::readvar`) and not from within the `Session::couple`.

Answer (score 2):

When `io_context` runs out of work, it returns from `run()`.

If you don't post any work, `run()` will always immediately return. Any subsequent `run()` also immediately returns, even if new work was posted.

To re-use `io_context` after it completed, use `io_context.reset()`. In your case, better to

1. use a work guard (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/executor_work_guard.html), see many of the library examples
2. don't even "run" the `ioc` in `couple()` if you already run it on a background thread

If you need synchronous behaviour, don't run it on a background thread.

Also keep in mind that you need to afford graceful shutdown which is strictly harder with a detached thread - after all, now you can't `join()` it to know when it exited.

Comment: Quite the contrary seems to be true: ```io_context.run()``` never return because it never runs out of work (it is being kept alive from the MQTT server). As a result, the thread gets blocked as soon as I enter the ```run()``` method and I cannot send any publish and subscribe frames anymore. That was when I thought it would be clever to run the ```io_context``` in a separate thread to not block the main thread. However, when I ```detach``` this separate thread, the connection runs into an error, if I use ```join``` however, it works fine but the main thread gets blocked again.

Comment: Just join only at program exit? (And remove the run from `couple()`, but guessing by your comment, that could have been oversight)